# Ruby posting field as JSON is empty in before_validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

**Edit:** Here is the POST data and ruby log:

Ruby log:

```
Started PUT "/things/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-28 10:54:32 -0700
Processing by ThingController#update as JSON
Parameters: {
    "name"=>"Name",
    "image_data"=>"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG...",
    "id"=>"1",

    "Thing" => {
        "name"=>"Name"
    }
}
```

POSTed JSON data:

```
{
    "name":"Name",
    "image_data":"data:image/png;base64,iVBORalksdfj"
}
```

**Why does the ruby log** show the full data, then just the Thing missing the extra field I sent?

---

My controller for updating allows this filed named `image_data`:

```
class ThingController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :html, :json

    def update
        @thing.update(thing_params)
        respond_with(@thing)
    end

    def thing_params
        params.require(:thing).permit(:name, :image_data) # allow it here
    end
end
```

The `image_data` field is not actually on the model but I create an accesor for it:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessor :image_data
    before_validation :decode_base64_image

    def decode_base64_image
        # Always empty!
        logger.debug image_data

        if image_data
            # Never gets here
        end
    end

end
```

`image_data` is never set on the commented lines. What gives? How can I access one field (image_data) in my validator and massage it into a different field (that's actually on the model?).

Comment: and the name is assigned?

Comment: @Fer what do you mean, is the name assigned?

Comment: @AndyRay chang this and try         `@thing.update_attributes(thing_params)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your POST json structure like

```
{    
    "Thing" : {
        "name" : "Name",
        "image_data" : "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG..."
    }
}
```

So `image_data` will be a child of `Thing`

Comment: I think this is the answer but that's not formatted as JSON. The problem was I needed to POST the JSON as { thing: { data } }, not just data alone.

Comment: @AndyRay Of course I just gave sample to demonstrate